# Error: 'typeOf' is not exported by node_modules\react-is\index.js, imported by node_modules\styled-components\dist\styled-components.browser.esm.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, microbundle

When I try to run, breaks in `npm start` (`microbundle-crl --no-compress --format modern,cjs`)

I've tried delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and run `npm i` again and nothing.

**react**: 17.0.2

**styled-components**: 5.3.3

**microbundle-crl**: 0.13.10

[Image build broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNBL5.png)

Comment: Fixed!
I've put `styled-components` in peerDependencies and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

I've put `styled-components` in `peerDependencies`, in `package.json` and it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).